# Open one submenu at a time React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS and I am creating sidebar menu with submenu for my project.

**Problem** : When I try to open the submenu, all submenus are getting open.

Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-sunset-qx7kxq?file=/src/App.js:0-95).

I am open to other solutions as well.

App.js

```
import Menu from "./components/Menu/Menu";
export default function App() {
  return <Menu />;
}
```

Menu.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import SubMenu from './SubMenu'
import MenuItems from './menuData'


const Menu = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)  

  const clickHandler = () => {
    console.log(`clicked`)  
    setToggle(!toggle)
  }

  return (
    <nav>
        <ul>
          {
              MenuItems.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={item.menuname} onClick={item.submenu && clickHandler}>
                      {item.menuname}
                      {item.submenu && toggle ? <SubMenu dropDownItem={item.submenu} /> : null}
                      </li>
                    )
              })
          }
        </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Menu
```

SubMenu.js

```
import React from 'react'

const SubMenu = ({dropDownItem}) => {
  return (
    <div className='drop-down'>
        <ul>
            {dropDownItem.map((item) => {
                return <li key={item.submenuname}>{item.submenuname}</li>
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SubMenu
```

menuData.js

```
const MenuItems = [
    {
        "menuname": 'Home',
        "submenu": [
            {"submenuname": "Home Child 1"},
            {"submenuname": "Home Child 2"},
            {"submenuname": "Home Child 3"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "menuname": 'About',
        "submenu": [
            {"submenuname": "About Child 1"},
            {"submenuname": "About Child 2"},
            {"submenuname": "About Child 3"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "menuname": 'Contact'
    }
]

export default MenuItems
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because you have one single toggle state for all items.
A possible solution might be to define the state in each single ItemMenu and then u can check for the state to show or hide the Submenu item.

Like this:

```
const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {MenuItems.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.menuname}>
              <MenuItem item={item} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

And this is the MenuItem :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const MenuItem = ({ item }) => {
  const [isSubMenuShow, setIsSubMenuShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setIsSubMenuShow(!isSubMenuShow)}>
        {item.menuname}
      </div>
      {item.submenu && isSubMenuShow && <SubMenu dropDownItem={item.submenu} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const SubMenu = ({ dropDownItem }) => {
  return (
    <div className="drop-down">
      <ul>
        {dropDownItem.map((item) => {
          return <li key={item.submenuname}>{item.submenuname}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

Hope that this did help you.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-lalande-ojjtj2?file=/src/components/Menu/ItemMenu.js 
this is the solution on codesandbox if needed

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Upvote...just want to know one thing, can we create a new component called `SubMenu.js` and use it with this solution?

Comment: Yes you can put the SubMenu component in a separate file like SubMenu.js
And then u import it in the MenuItem component to be used.

Comment: Thanks for giving the time..really appreciate that...Answer Accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

it's because you set a general state for handle toggle sub menus, you should change your state for example like below

```js
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(null)  
const clickHandler = (menuId) => {
    console.log(`clicked`)  
    setToggle(menuId)
  }

return (
    <nav>
        <ul>
          {
              MenuItems.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={item.menuname} onClick={clickHandler(item.id)}>
                      {item.menuname}
                      {item.submenu && toggle == item.id ? <SubMenu dropDownItem={item.submenu} /> : null}
                      </li>
                    )
              })
          }
        </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

I gave you an example and you can set any unique value instead of item id and pass it to you handler to set in your state

Answer (score -1):

You need an array for every submenu indexing and give it perspective index.

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react'
    import SubMenu from './SubMenu'
    import MenuItems from './menuData'
    
    
    const Menu = () => {
      const [toggle, setToggle] = useState([])  
    
      const clickHandler = (i) => {
let tempToggle = [...toggle]
if(tempToggle[i]){
tempToggle[i]=false


}
else{
tempToggle[i]=true

}
setToggle(tempToggle)
      }
    
      return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
              {
                  MenuItems.map((item,i) => {
                      return (
                        <li key={item.menuname} onClick={item.submenu && clickHandler}>
                          {item.menuname}
                          {item.submenu && toggle[i] ? <SubMenu dropDownItem={item.submenu} /> : null}
                          </li>
                        )
                  })
              }
            </ul>
        </nav>
      )
    }
    
    export default Menu
```