# React state open all submenu instead of only the one clicked, want to use only one state for all my menu items

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a react app where I render this information in a component:

```
const navigation = [
  {
    name: "Services",
    description: "Our services",
    href: "#",
    subMenu: [
      { name: "Management" },
      { name: "Development" },
      { name: "Specialists" },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Experts",
    description: "our experts",
    href: "#",
    subMenu: [
      { name: "Engineers" },
      { name: "Project managers" },
      { name: "Developers" },
      { name: "Cloud solutions" },
    ],
  },
```

So "description" is the "header" for each submenu and "name" is each item in the submenu.

Im setting the following state:

```
 const [ShowSubMenu, setShowSubMenu] = useState(false);
```

This is where I render the submenu in my component:

```
{navigation.map((item) => (
            <>
              <div
                onClick={() => setShowSubMenu(!ShowSubMenu)}
                className=" border-b-2 justify-between pb-4 pl-2 font-bold flex "
              >
                <h3 className=" text-roboto">{item.description}</h3>
                <div className="border-solid border-b-2"></div>
                <ChevronDownIcon
                  className={ShowSubMenu ? "rotate-90 h-5 w-5" : "h-5 w-5 "}
                />
              </div>

              <div className=" flex flex-col">
                {item.subMenu.map((sm) => (
                  <div
                    key={sm.name}
                    className={!ShowSubMenu ? "hidden" : " pl-2 pt-2"}
                  >
                    {sm.name}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
```

I get that since my submenu opens depending on state, it will open all the submenus. How do I fix so that it knows which item is clicked and as such only opens the children for that item? I thought that the "key" prop would let it figure this out. I don't want to have an individual useState for each item unless nesseccary. Thanks for help!

TLDR: Click changes state which opens all submenus. Want to open only the submenu for item clicked while only using one useState statement.

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox for this ?

Comment: There is something really useful when dealing with arrays called... index!

So here instead of using boolean value for your state you can use index of the menu that should be open.

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217779/open-one-submenu-at-a-time-react-js

Answer (score 2):

for better use of "useState" you can store the name of the item which should be open and handle display with a function that get name of item and expand it if its name matches with one of if conditions inside the function.
for example here you can use this:

```
 const [expandedSubMenu, setExpandedSubMenu] = useState();
```

and

```
{navigation.map((item) => (
        <>
          <div
            onClick={() => setExpandedSubMenu(item.description)}
            className=" border-b-2 justify-between pb-4 pl-2 font-bold flex "
          >
            <h3 className=" text-roboto">{item.description}</h3>
            <div className="border-solid border-b-2"></div>
            <ChevronDownIcon
              className={expandedSubMenu === item.description ? "rotate-90 h-5 w-5" : "h-5 w-5 "}
            />
          </div>

          <div display={expandedSubMenu === item.description ? "flex" : "none"} className=" flex flex-col">
            {item.subMenu.map((sm) => (
              <div
                key={sm.name}
                className={expandedSubMenu === item.description ? "hidden" : " pl-2 pt-2"}
              >
                {sm.name}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> want to use only one state for all my menu items

That state still needs to in some way be able to indicate *which* element is "open".  A single boolean value doesn't store this information.

You can instead perhaps track an identifier for the record in state.  How are your records uniquely identified?  The `name` value?  If so, use that as the state value.  Something like this:

```
const [ShowSubMenu, setShowSubMenu] = useState();
```

Which defaults to `undefined`, implying that no element is currently "open".  Then to set one to "open":

```
setShowSubMenu(item.name)
```

And to hide it:

```
setShowSubMenu(undefined)
```

Or to toggle in a one-liner, perhaps something like:

```
setShowSubMenu(ShowSubMenu ? undefined : item.name)
```

Or when clicking on another menu and wanting to close the currently open one, that *might* look more like this:

```
setShowSubMenu(ShowSubMenu === item.name ? undefined : item.name)
```

There are a variety of tweaks you can make for the individual click handlers you're creating.

Then when displaying the elements, check if `ShowSubMenu` matches the element:

```
className={ShowSubMenu === item.name ? "rotate-90 h-5 w-5" : "h-5 w-5 "}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing this could be to create multiple states, one for each dropdown as so,

```
const [showServices, setShowService] = useState(false);
const [showExperts, setShowExperts] = useState(false);
```

This however can become tedious as the project scales.
alternatively you can combine these to create one which can handle any boolean value which is added.

```
const [bool, setBool] = useState({});
setBool({ ...bool, ['services']: true });
setBool({ ...bool, ['experts']: true });

console.log(bool['services'])
```

This method creates a new key, value pair without mutating the original state of the object. which can then be updated using the same syntax to switch between true or false. and each boolean value can be accessed to handle different components seperately.

I think it is worth mentioning that state can be stored as objects, or as an array and these arrays or objects can be updated using the rest operator in a lot of different ways